# Defining cell-based change authorization to specific users in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Different people need to edit an excel file shared on OneDrive. Since work is done on the same sheet, people should only be able to change the cells under their responsibility. I can encrypt cell sets using "Allow edit ranges", but I couldn't find how to do person-based authorization. I would be glad if you help.

I can encrypt cell sets using "Allow edit ranges", but I couldn't find how to do person-based authorization. I would be glad if you help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give cell-level access to users in Excel. However, you can try splitting the sheets for each user. You can also try Microsoft SharePoint or Airtable, which can provide more granular access control.